# Combining multiple count items in python?

Tags: python

```
return function.count('1') + given.count('2') + given.count('3')
```

is there any way I can simplify this line?
also i've tried
return function.count('1', '2', '3') but runs an error
the goal is to count all numbers contained in the string lol

Comment: Is `function` different than `given`?

Comment: Please clarify the question, define your input and your desired output more carefully. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `function` is the same as `given`,

```
sum(function.count(x) for x in '1 2 3'.split())
```

The variable name `function` (and `given`) is somewhat confusing since the question also says

> *the goal is to count all numbers contained in the string*.

So if `function` is a string and you wish to extend the count to all digits you could use

```
import string
sum(function.count(x) for x in string.digits)
```

This suffices if `function` is a short string. But note that each call to `count` requires a full pass through the string `function`. If `function` is a very large string, doing 10 passes may be inefficient.

In that case, it may be better to discard characters that are not digits *in one pass*:

```
def onepass(x):
    return sum(1 for c in x if c in string.digits)
```

Or, you could remove all the non-digits from the string (using the [translate method](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.translate)) and then use `len`. For example:

```
def drop_nondigits(x):
    # The essential idea comes from the translator recipe in Python Cookbook;
    # It can also be found here
    # http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303342-simple-wrapper-for-stringtranslate/
    keep = string.digits
    allchars = string.maketrans('', '')
    delete = allchars.translate(allchars, keep)
    return len(x.translate(allchars, delete))
```

And out of curiosity, let's compare it to using [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections
def using_counter(x):
    counter = collections.Counter(x)
    return sum(counter[d] for d in string.digits)
```

It turns out that **`drop_nondigits` is fastest**:

```
In [26]: x = 'some very large string 123456' * 1000

In [38]: %timeit using_counter(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.26 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit onepass(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.52 ms per loop

In [32]: %timeit drop_nondigits(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.9 us per loop
```

Comment: This would take one linear pass per `x` in `'1 2 3'.split()`. A better solution would do one linear pass. So using `Counter` might be a better idea

Comment: Spliting the string `'1 2 3'` is trivial. You could just as easily use `['1', '2', '3']`, I just think `'1 2 3'.split()` reads better. The problem with using `Counter` is that you may be counting a lot of things you have no interest in.

Comment: The bottleneck in efficiency comes from n linear passes where `n = len("1 2 3".split())`. Using `collections.Counter` wastes some space in counting things we don't care about, but it's only one linear pass.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Right. Sorry I misunderstood your point the first time. I hope I've addressed it now in my post.

Answer (score 2):

use `Counter()` to count all numbers contained in the string:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> count= Counter("abcd12341134..09--01abc")
>>> [x for x in count.items() if x[0] in "0123456789"]
[('1', 4), ('0', 2), ('3', 2), ('2', 1), ('4', 2), ('9', 1)]
```

or using `Counter()` with `filter()`:

```
>>> strs="abcd12341134..09--01abc"
>>> Counter(filter(lambda x:x in "0123456789",strs))
Counter({'1': 4, '0': 2, '3': 2, '4': 2, '2': 1, '9': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this be sufficiently faster?

```
count = Counter(strings) 
sum(v for k, v in count.items() if k in "0123456789")
```